# Mongoose query to keep only 50 documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I make a query in mongoose to find if a user has 50 documents then remove the oldest one and add in the new one, if not just add in the new one?

This is my attempt:

```
    Notifications.findOne({_id: userId}, function(err, results) {
       if(err) throw err;
       if(results.length < 50) {
         saveNotification();
       } else {
          Notifications.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {pull: //WHAT GOES HERE), 
            function(err, newNotify) {
              if(error) throw error;
               saveNotification();
            });

       }
    });

function saveNotification() { 

    var new_notification = new Notification ({
        notifyToUserId: creatorId,
        notifyFromUserId: null,
        notifyMsg: newmsg,
        dateNotified: dateLastPosted                
    });

    new_notification.save(function(err, results){
        if(!err) {
           console.log('notification has been added to the db');
           cb(null, resultObject);
        } else {
           console.log("Error creating notification " + err);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Btw your code won't enter the if since you're using `findOne`, that will always return a single document.

Comment: Why don't you simplify and just cut of later? It doesn't have to be strictly sync, does it?
Like: `Notifications.insert().then(reduceThemTo50);` An added bonus is that even if it fails to remove the old ones at one query, it'll just be done on the next insert. And when requesting users' notifications, just `limit(50)` them.

Answer (score 2):

As @Pio mentioned I don't think you can do it in one query with your current schema. But if you have chance to change the schema, you can use fixed size array pattern that is described in the following article [Limit Number of Elements in an Array after an Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/)

Basically you can keep the notifications of users in one document. Key of the document will be userId, and notifications will be stored in an array. Then the following query would achieve your goal.

```
Notifications.update(
   { _id: userId },
   {
     $push: {
        notifications: {
           $each: [ notificationObject ], // insert your new notification
           $sort: { dateNotified: 1 }, // sort by insertion date
           $slice: -50 // retrieve the last 50 notifications.
        }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: This is simple and elegant. Notifications should be small objects and are suited to arrays. Capped collections was mentioned elsewhere, but doing that per user? Complex! A good simple example for people to follow. Or drop the `$sort` and use [`$position`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) to implement a FIFO.

Comment: Interesting, I can switch the schema to this possibly, but if there is less than 50 would slice affect anything or it will be ignored in the query?

Comment: it wouldnt remove any items from the array as the number of items in the array is less than 50.

Comment: It needs to be reworded because I need to use findOneAndUpdate and it will be storing one object at a time, so each I dont think has to be called? or how does that work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do it in one query, but you can
`.count({user: yourUser'})` then depending on the count `.insert(newDocument)` or update the oldest one so you won't remove + insert.

Comment: Can you give me an example of update, not sure how it works so that the oldest document is replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Capped collections do what you want by nature. If you define a capped collection with size 50 it will only keep 50 documents and will overwrite old data when you insert more.
check

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#capped
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

```html
new Schema({..}, { capped: { size: 50, max: 50, autoIndexId: true } });
```

Remember that when working with capped collection you can only make inplace updates. Updating whole document may change the size of collection that will remove other documents.

Comment: So he should keep a collection per user?

Comment: Yeah I would not keep a collection per user

Comment: @Zlatko  sorry my bad I did not focus on the model and query

Comment: Capped collections have a load of limitations.  Such as not being able to update their records.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
I ended up using cubbuk's answer and expanding it to add a notification if there is no array to start with along with upsert... 

Notification.findOneAndUpdate({notifyToUserId: to}, {
            $push: { 
                notifyArray: {$each: [newNotificationObject], // insert your new notification
                   $sort: { dateNotified: 1 }, // sort by insertion date
                   $slice: -50 // retrieve the last 50 notifications.
                }
            }
        }, {upsert: true}, function(err, resultOfFound) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(resultOfFound == null) {
                var new_notification = new Notification ({
                    notifyToUserId: to,
                    notifyArray: [newNotificationObject]
                });
                new_notification.save(function(err, results){
                    if(!err) {

                        console.log('notification has been added to the db');
                        cb(null, resultObject);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error creating notification " + err);


                    }
                });

            } else {
                cb(null, resultObject);
            }
        });
```